# Write sequlize migration to update table onDelete attribute

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using sequlize ORM, I have migration file to create associations between tables:

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.addColumn('testSessions', 'patientId', {
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      references: {
        model: 'patients',
        key: 'id',
      },
      onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
      onDelete: 'SET NULL',
    });
  },
  down: async queryInterface => {
    await queryInterface.removeColumn('testSessions', 'patientId');
  },
};
```

I want to change **onDelete** key to 'CASCADE'. Is it possible to write a migration that would change the value of the **onDelete** attribute?
I don't want to lose the data I have in the table so undoing migration and running is not a solution for me.

Do you know if you can write a migration that will override the **onDelete** value, how would it look like?

Answer (score 0):

Just write SQL query that removes constraint and then adds constraint using **sequelize.query** something like below:

```
var table = 'YOURTABLENAME';
var constraint = 'YOURCONSTRAINTNAME';
var constraintFkey = 'CONSTRAINTFKEY';

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.sequelize.query(`alter table "${table}" drop constraint "${constraint}"`)
      .then(() => queryInterface.sequelize.query(
        `alter table "${table}"
          add constraint "${constraint}" foreign key("${constraintFkey}") references "property_service" ("id")
          on delete cascade`
      ));
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.sequelize.query(`alter table "${tableName}" drop constraint "${constraintName}"`)
      .then(() => queryInterface.sequelize.query(
        `alter table "${tableName}"\
          add constraint "${constraintName}" foreign key("${constraintFkey}") references "patients" ("id")
          on delete no action`
      ));
  },
};
```